# What happened internally in nodejs when pause a response

Tags: node.js

As the nodejs [document](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) said:

> This method will cause a stream in flowing-mode to stop emitting data
>   events. Any data that becomes available will remain in the internal
>   buffer.

When I pause a response in client(We know this response is a http.IncomingMessage). Does the client just stop reading data from server or continue read data but store them in buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It buffers data up to `highWaterMark` bytes and then stops reading from the socket when it hits that limit.

Comment: Thanks! When it stops reading, does it keep the tcp connection?

Comment: The connection stays open unless something explicitly closes it (e.g. the client, the server, or the OS).